# Cannot get rid of logs in Azure Function for Web Storage

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have tried so many things to do this and nothing works, but when I run my Azure function I get all these logs its far too much noise

What is the correct way to get rid of them once and for all?

I have this in my host.json

```
 "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "System": "Warning",
      "Host": "Error",
      "Function": "Error",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Information"
    },
    "Serilog": {
      "MinimumLevel": "Information",
      "WriteTo": [
        {
          "Name": "Console",
          "Args": {
            "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level} | {RequestId} - {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

and this is in my localsettings.json

```
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Middleware.SystemTraceMiddleware": "Error",
      "Worker.rpcWorkerProcess": "Error"
    }
  },
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the  `host.json`  for configuring minimum level of logs either locally or in Azure Cloud.
I can see you have defined the log values as  `Information`,  `Warning`  to the Log Level attributes where  `information`  gives the general flow of the Application Execution from Start to End like Host level flow, Application-Level Flow logs.

`Host.Aggregator`  generates more than the trace level metrics if assigned with the value of  `Information`.

You have to remove/disable the unnecessary modules which are not required for logs or keep that modules log level to None if not required for the current situation and change the log level to minimum which also reduces your Logs Consumption if deployed to Azure Cloud.

I found a similar SO Issue  [70690850](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70690850/16630138)  that shows the minimum log levels should be modified in the  `host.json`  which reduces the number of logs both locally and given the techniques of Application Insights and this  [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-log-levels)  for more information on Log Levels Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same issue that can be found here: [How to disable durable function verbose logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75437555/how-to-disable-durable-function-verbose-logging/77955703#77955703)

To achieve this, you'll need to disable logging for Functions or set it to your preferred log level, then specify the log level for user logging for each function individually. Unfortunately, there's no universal setting for user logging, so you'll have to configure it for each function separately.

Here's an example provided by the URL, which I've tested locally and confirmed to be effective. In your local.settings.json file:

```
{
    "logging:logLevel:Microsoft": "None",
    "logging:logLevel:Worker": "None",
    "AzureFunctionsJobHost:logging:logLevel:default": "None",
    "AzureFunctionsJobHost:logging:logLevel:Host.Function.Console": "Information",
    "AzureFunctionsJobHost:logging:logLevel:Function.HttpTrigger1.User": "Information",
    "AzureFunctionsJobHost:logging:logLevel:Function.HttpTrigger2.User": "Information"
}
```