# How to reuse Azure Functions premium plan?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function Premium plan for a C# function. I need this because my function needs to be deployed inside a VNET. Now I need to deploy another Python function. Can I reseuse my Premium plan? If I understand correctly it's a "server" which is running forever but which is only "used" when a function is triggered. Running two such a servers will be expensive and overkill for my functions.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, you can run multiple Azure Function Apps in the same premium hosting plan, but the limitation is they should both run on same operating system either windows or Linux**.

> Running two such a servers will be expensive

Yes, it is expensive because of pre-warmed instances and always ready instances but predictable pricing.

**The main 3 factors considered on Azure Functions are Application Insights, Network Traffic and Storage Account**.

As per my experience,

- **Storage account** is used by Azure functions for its internal state in which these costs are negligible.
- When the functions are sending the **traffic** the outside world (Egress traffic), then the **networking** fees would occur which is usually low but may raise cost for high-volume data sending by the Azure Function.
- **Application Insights cost** is the main factor we have to monitor and optimize. Refer to these few workarounds ([Thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70683888) & [Thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70710494)) for optimizing cost in Azure Function - App Insights.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Can you show me how I can run multiple function apps on the same hosting plan?